# How to get my Knockout code to bind properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a shoppingcart page which I am building with KnockoutJS 3.4.2. I test this in the latest Chrome. The products in the cart are being loaded by Ajax.

The shoppingcart is then filled in an HTML table.

For some reason when I bind 'productTitle' in the TD it works but when I try to bind it in a span it won't. I also tried to use templating: `<span><!--ko text: productTitle--><!--/ko--></span>` but this also won't work.

Does it has something to do with the fact that when the page is loaded the observableArray could still be empty? I found that when I put 'productTitle' in the TD text bind the text works.

Also for some reason the observable count won't bind to an input on the data-bind value. Maybe the way my viewModel is constructed is wrong?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: productsInCart">
                <tr data-bind="attr: {productOptionId: productOptionId}">
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="cart-title" data-bind="text: productTitle"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
                    <td>
                        @*<span><!--ko text: productTitle--><!--/ko--></span>*@
                            <div click-action="" class="qtyminus"></div>
                            <input type='text' name="quantity" data-bind="value: count" class="qty"/>
                            <div click-action="" class="qtyplus"></div>                        
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart-total" data-bind="text: total"></td>@*
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("RemoveProductOption", "ShoppingCart", new {id = product.ProductOptionId})" class="cart-remove"></a></td>*@
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

JS

```
$(function () {  
    var productInCart = function(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.productOptionId = ko.observable(data.ProductOptionId);
        self.price = ko.observable(data.Price);
        self.count = ko.observable(data.Count);
        self.productBrandName = ko.observable(data.ProductBrandName);
        self.productOptionName = ko.observable(data.ProductOptionName);
        self.productName = ko.observable(data.ProductName);
        self.productFriendlyUrl = ko.observable(data.ProductFriendlyUrl);

        self.productTitle = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.productName() + " " + self.productOptionName();
        });

        self.total = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.count() * self.price();
        }, self);

        return self;
    }

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.productsInCart = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: window.cartUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            traditional: true, //// traditional option to true
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(result, function (data) {
                    self.productsInCart.push(new productInCart(data));
                });
                console.log(self.productsInCart());
            }
        });
    }

    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

The object being loaded by AJAX:

```
[
{
ShoppingSessionId: 2061,
ProductOptionId: 3,
Price: 26.95,
Count: 1,
ProductBrandName: "G-Star",
ProductOptionName: "Maat 36/36",
ProductName: "G-Star Loose, 340166",
ProductFriendlyUrl: "g-star-3301-loose-dus",
TaxId: 1,
TaxRate: 21,
FirstProductImageId: 7,
Id: 48
}
]
```

One of the not able to bind errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return count }"
Message: count is not defined
    at value (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-3.4.2.js:280), <anonymous>:3:58)
    at m (knockout-3.4.2.js:470)
    at Function.Uc (knockout-3.4.2.js:204)
    at Function.Vc (knockout-3.4.2.js:201)
    at Function.U (knockout-3.4.2.js:200)
    at Object.a.m.a.B (knockout-3.4.2.js:193)
    at init (knockout-3.4.2.js:472)
    at knockout-3.4.2.js:309
    at Object.w (knockout-3.4.2.js:149)
    at knockout-3.4.2.js:308
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: To this arriving here, the issue was caused by a third-party library (StackTable) which was augmenting the KO bindings.

It looks like your code is razor? I notice the `<span></span>` is commented out. Is this the problematic span you mention?

If so, I would recommend placing the binding on the `<span>` element itself. I am not certain the text binding supports virtual tag use.

Replace:

```
<span><!--ko text: productTitle--><!--/ko--></span>
```

With:

```
<span data-bind="text: productTitle"></span>
```

Also, as a means of "best practice" I wouldn't push the elements individual into the array. Each push causes knockout to re-evaulate dependencies, and will/might cause a redraw (i.e. not so good for performance). Instead:

1. Build a local plain old JavaScript array.
2. Push the items into it.
3. Set the value of your observable array to be that of the local array you've just built.

I would also wrap the `foreach` in a logical check to determine that the array is not null/undefined or empty. To prevent any potential bindings errors.

Comment: What's the point of using two HTML templating tools - Razor *and* Knockout anyway? I've never really understood this. Are there any things Knockout can't do?

Comment: Yup. Server rendering. SEO plays a big part in most sites, so the server rendering can be vital in some cases.

Comment: Okay, but when you render on the server, why do you render on the client? Anyway, two notes: the `text` binding is supported as on a virtual element (all bindings are), your replacement suggestion will not change anything. And: I agree with your 3 steps, but they could be rolled into one by using Array#map (or ko.utils.arrayMap).

Comment: Well, thinking about it, scratch "all bindings". "attribute" doesn't really make sense, for example.

Comment: Hi Pim,

Thanks for your answer and suggestion about the filling of the array. Unfortunately the binding in the span isn't working as you mentioned. I tried to explain but failed sorry. I indeed porgram in ASP.NET MVC Razor. The error I am getting is that the productTitle is unable to bind. You what weird is: This works -> <td class="cart-title" data-bind="text: productTitle"></td> 

This fails -> <span data-bind="text: productTitle"></span>.

I just don't understand

Comment: Also the: count property is unable to bind with. How come..? Is this a reserved word?

Comment: Shouldn't be. "length" would be the JavaScript equivalent of count.

Comment: But why is this still not working? Any other ideas? I find it strange that the span bind also doesn't work. Templating also not working;( I am out of ideas...

Comment: @LeroyMeijer Can you do a `<!-- ko if: productsInCart() -->` check to ensure the view model is initialized before it attempts to iterate?

Comment: @PimBrouwers We could be on to something here. If I put this around my table, the foreach isn't triggered and nothing is happening. Also no error message.

Comment: @LeroyMeijer before your foreach and if place the following code `<pre data-bind="ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)></pre>`. This is a common technique from the KO docs that will output the view model within the current context as JSON. Which will allow you to explore it more easily.

Comment: @PimBrouwers I have the debug information. I needed to adjust the bit you sent to: `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>` to get it to work.

debug -> : `{
  "productsInCart": [
    {
      "productOptionId": 3,
      "price": 26.95,
      "count": 1,
      "productBrandName": "G-Star",
      "productOptionName": "Maat 36/36",
      "productName": "G-Star Loose, 340166",
      "productFriendlyUrl": "g-star-3301-loose-dus",
      "productTitle": "G-Star Loose, 340166 Maat 36/36",
      "total": 26.95
    }
  ]
}` But count is still not binding in the input..?

Comment: @LeroyMeijer my apolgoies, forgot the binding name there! I'm so stupid. I should've seen this immediately. Change both `ko.computed` to `ko.pureComputed`. Those computed's are being evaluated when the view model is built, as opposed to when their values are requested. Hence your issue.

Comment: @PimBrouwers  does that explain why count won't bind in an input?

Comment: @LeroyMeijer I suspect the error is actually occurring because of this `text: total` binding. Please update and let me know.

Comment: @LeroyMeijer I would also recommend changing the setter to this `self.count = ko.observable(data.Count || 0);`

Comment: @PimBrouwers `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return count }"
Message: count is not defined`. I still don't know if it is better or not. If I remove `<input type="text" data-bind="value: count" name="quantity" class="qty"/>`  this from within my td I see binding happening as other data is being binded but directly in the td element it self.

Comment: @LeroyMeijer hmmm out of curiosity can you rename it to `productCount` or `itemCount`. And see if the error persists?

Comment: @PimBrouwers It persists... hmmmm, I'm running out of options to... 
There is no difference between string or number in a input bind right?

Comment: @LeroyMeijer At this point, unless this is in a jsfiddle where I can debug myself I don't think I can offer much more assistance. Apologies.

Comment: @PimBrouwers lol.... [link]https://jsfiddle.net/41tx8L27/3/ for some reason it works.... could be something with a different library or something else from within my template...

Comment: After seeing the light I found that on my table there was a class called: responsive-table. Removing this class made the binding correct. Further debugging learned that all element with this class where triggered with stacktable() which calls the stacktable.js lib [link]https://github.com/johnpolacek/stacktable.js/

We can say that knockoutJS and Stacktable don't get along very well. Thanks for the further help and suggestions! @PimBrouwers